# Bullmq get a job with a specific ID from a queue

Tags: node.js, bull, bullmq

I am trying to create a results queue on BullMQ where all workers can send results adding jobs with special crafted jobIDs. The idea is that all results arrive with a specific jobID generated so that I known exactly which process the result is for.

I've tried with `getNextJob` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.bullmq.io/patterns/manually-fetching-jobs), with no luck.

The solution I found is using the `queuEvents`: each process registers a listener on the `waiting` state of the results queue and,  when the job with the id It needs arrives, the process gets the job with a `getJob`, reads the result data and tries to move  the job to completed. It works and I can correctly grab the results produced by workers.

The problem I have is moving result jobs to the completed state, since I cannot configure a lock token with the `getJob` and I receive a `Missing lock for job` error and the job remains in the active state.

This is the (pseudo-)code I use on the process

```js
const jobID = "THE_ID_OF_THE_JOB_I_AM_WAITING_FOR";
const token = `${jobID}_results_worker`;
const queueEvents = new QueueEvents('results');
const resQueue = this.queues.get('results');
// I define a callback function to be able to remove the listener
const waitResult = async (job: {jobId: any}) => {
  if (job.jobId === jobID){
    debug(`Result job for ${jobID} received!`);
    const resJob = await resQueue?.getJob(jobID) as Job;
    queueEvents.removeListener('waiting', waitResult);
    // THIS GENERATES the error 
    resJob?.moveToCompleted('Results received', token, false);
    resolve(resJob?.data);
  }
} 
// Register the callback function on the queue
const listener = queueEvents?.on('waiting', waitResult );
```

Does anybody have any idea about how to correctly handle the `moveToCompleted`?

Comment: I partially solved the problem removing the result job from the queue with the command ``resQueue?.remove(jobID)``. This is sub-optimal since i lose the history of the results

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a `results` queue, like so: `const queue_Results = new Queue('Results');`, from there you could have a worker handle the event like so `const worker_Results = new Worker('Results', async (job: Job) => { // do something with the results from other jobs })`

BullMQ documentation about that method, [here](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/returning-job-data#using-a-results-queue)

Comment: The problem is that having a queue is not enough due to BullMQ model: if a worker gets a job, the job is removed from the queue. In my situation each worker is waiting its own response and I have a lot of workers since they are dynamically created. The way I have found is to have a single queue and use the ``queueEvents``  on each worker to see if something interesting happens on the queue and pull only the job each worker is waiting for. 

I'm trying to understand if this is a complete _anti-pattern_ or has some sense.